# wso2 api manager convert.xml sequence will be removed after started

Tags: error-handling, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using from wso2 api manager 4.1.0 and I want to handle errors according to https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/error-handling

When the server is up and I add the convert.xml file it's working But after restarting the server, the file will be deleted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following config to the `deployment.toml` to skip deletion.

```ini
[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway.skip_list]
sequences = ["custom_fault_sequence.xml"]
```

If you have multiple sequences you can add them as a comma-separated list.

```ini
[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway.skip_list]
sequences = ["auth_failure_handler_.xml", "production_key_error_.xml"]
```